# How to change user department in Navision 2009 (role tailored)

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

How can i change users deparments in Microsoft Dynamics NAV RoleTailored Client, say  i want to put myself in the [Purchase] department.

Please help.

Comment: I doubt you will find much of a response to NAV questions on Stackoverflow.com -- you will have much better luck in asking your question on a site that focuses specifically on NAV configuration and development, such as www.mibuso.com

Comment: Mibuso would greatly benefit from the infrastructure of Stack Overflow. Trawling through forums is time consuming. I'm all for promoting the dynamics-nav tag on Stack Overflow and the Area51 proposal for Microsoft Dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

In the RoleTailored Client, if you go into Departments->Administration->RoleTailored Client->User Personalization you can specify which role center each user has. From here, you can give yourself the Purchasing Agent role, for example.

You can do this programmatically from AL by manipulating table 20000000073: User Personalization.

In RoleTailored client it is not possible to change the departments menu itself. The idea is that you create a role center based on the pages and reports the user needs most frequently.